# Set dynamic value to a input type file

Tags: php, html, arrays, file-upload, dynamic

I have a form which reloads on submit with error if any input data is already there in database. After reload all input type value is remaining as it is. but, how can i give dynamic value to uploaded file?

Here is my HTML,

```
<input type="file" name="corporate_proof" id="corporate_proof" value="<?php if (isset($corporate_proof)) {print_r($corporate_proof);} else {'';}?>" class="custom-file-input form-control" />
```

And `$corporate_proof` value is like,

```
[corporate_proof] => Array
( 
[name] => Image_.png 
[type] => image/png 
[tmp_name] => /tmp/php0dTN0z 
[error] => 0 
[size] => 143 
)
```

Comment: You can't repopulate a file input. A solution would be to post the form using Ajax so the form doesn't reload.

Comment: Explain what you thought you were trying to achieve, maybe we can suggest a way to achieve that